# Saivite rasarnava tradition

Tags: moksha, tantra, shaivism

Does somebody have any idea about this rasarnava tradition as in is it still alive and how can I increase my lifespan using mercury as these guys of this saivite rasarnava tradition did. I want to increase my lifespan not because I am afraid of death or some stupid shit like that , but because I want to realise brahman in this lifetime but dont have the time to actually practice yoga other than karma yoga, so I want to ensure after fulfilling my duties I increase my lifespan using techniques of this tradition to then spend the rest of my life after the age of 50 or 60 solely on proper raja yoga meditation to achieve brahman before dying and not achieving it and then taking birth again and spend the first 20 years of my life again reading about brahman from upanishads and that even when I get lucky like i did in this life.

TLDR: need books or people who know how to increase lifespan by atleast a 100 years as mentioned in rasarnava tradition to ensure I realise brahman in this life.

Comment: If you want to increase your lifespan using Tantra, doing it under the personal guidance of a qualified guru is strongly advisable @DeepanshuMolasi

Comment: @SK I know that a guru is a must but I dont know where to find such a man and that is why I specifically asked if anybody knows if this tradition is alive or not. Everybody says its important to learn these things under a guru but nobody actually tells me the place they are found , and i feel this is injustice since these people who do know all this secretive knowledge just go in a cave or in himalayas and meditate in peace instead of giving other people who are genuinly interested a chance to make use of it.  Why do only these people deserve this knowledge why cant I too learn it.

Comment: Hindu tradition says when you are ready, the guru would just show up.  until then, use common sense and don't pursue practices that could be dangerous to the uninitiated @DeepanshuMolasi